# Clickable ad banner on loading screen is ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios, banner

I want to add clickable ad banned on launch screen of my app, how can I do that? Help me, please. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the default splash screen is just an image so if you want to add an ad to the launch screen you will need to make custom view that changes after some time. Here is a good tutorial for adding [iAd integration to iPhone application](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app).